# using pyodbc.cursor cause error in python

Tags: python

I am following this [github link](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started) to insert into sql server

here is my code

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=******;'
                      'Database=******;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = pyodbc.cursor()
```

I am getting this error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<ipython-input-33-d56faea8bdd3>", line 11, in <module>
>     cursor = pyodbc.cursor()
> 
> AttributeError: module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `conn.cursor` instead of `pyodbc.cursor`

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=******;'
                      'Database=******;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Refer [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection) for more details